# iOS 8 add share extension on office

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I want to add share extension on office like word/PPt/Xls , does anyone know how to do. I try to set NSExtensionAttributes as below but it don't work, my APP doesn't show in the share sheet options in shared extension.

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                    <real>1</real>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                    <real>1</real>
                </dict>
            </dict>
```